# why phpseclib SSH2 dont run commands?

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssh, phpseclib

i have the next script that use PHPSECLIB ver1.0 to connect to ubuntu server and install unifi controller ssl certificate.

The step for install the ssl certificate are the correct, the problem is that code stop in the write functions and dont run the commands.

how i can make my script run all the commands correctly?

````
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');

include ("Crypt/RSA.php");
include ("Net/SSH2.php");
include ("Net/SFTP.php");

$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('key.ppk'));

$ip = "my ip";
$username = "ubuntu";

$ssh = new Net_SSH2($ip);
$sftp = new Net_SFTP($ip);
$ssh_login = $ssh->login($username, $key);
$sftp_login = $sftp->login($username, $key);

$pfx_content = file_get_contents("key/test_file.pfx");
$pfx_name = "test_file.pfx";
$pfx_password = "unifiadmin";


if (!$ssh_login) {
    exit("SSH Login Failed");
}

if (!$sftp_login) {
    exit("SFTP Login Failed");
}
$import_key = "";
$import_key .= "sudo keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore";
$import_key .= " $pfx_name -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias 1";
$import_key .= " -destkeystore /usr/lib/unifi/data/keystore";
$import_key .= " -deststoretype jks -destalias unifi";
$import_key .= " -deststorepass aircontrolenterprise";
$import_key .= " -srcstorepass unifiadmin";

$migrate_key = "";
$migrate_key .= " sudo keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore";
$migrate_key .= " /usr/lib/unifi/data/keystore -srcstoretype JKS ";
$migrate_key .= " -destkeystore /usr/lib/unifi/data/keystore ";
$migrate_key .= " -deststoretype PKCS12 ";
$migrate_key .= " -srcstorepass aircontrolenterprise";
$migrate_key .= " -destkeypass unifiadmin";

function get_prompt($ssh){
    echo "<pre>".$ssh->read("[prompt]")."</pre>";
}

$upload_pfx = $sftp->put($pfx_name, $pfx_content);

$ssh->exec("clear");
get_prompt($ssh);

$ssh->write("sudo service unifi stop\n");
get_prompt($ssh);

$ssh->write("ls\n");
get_prompt($ssh);

$ssh->write($import_key."\n");
get_prompt($ssh);

$ssh->write("yes\n");
get_prompt($ssh);

$ssh->write($migrate_key."\n");
get_prompt($ssh);

$ssh->write($pfx_password."\n");
get_prompt($ssh);

$ssh->write("sudo service unifi restart\n");
get_prompt($ssh);

$ssh->write("sudo service unifi start\n");
get_prompt($ssh);```
````

Comment: So the `$sftp->put($pfx_name, $pfx_content);` is working correctly? `$ssh->exec("clear");` idk what you're hoping that'll accomplish. Based on the way you have your lines of code grouped it's like you think that that first `get_prompt()` call is reading a prompt produced by `$ssh->exec()`. It isn't. You _do_ need to read the prompt before you read the first command so that first `get_prompt()` call should be there, before the first `$ssh->write()` but the `$ssh->exec()`...  I don't see what point that serves.

Comment: `$ssh->write("sudo service unifi stop\n");`...  that first sudo could very well be prompting you for a password. See http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#sudo for how to deal with that

Comment: Also, what'd help me diagnose this further is seeing the SSH2 logs. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3);` at the top. Using 3 as opposed to 2 will get you the real time logs since it's not completely clear what your issue is (is your code hanging on a particular `get_prompt()` or is it running all the way through? etc)